# How to fill canvas with an image in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

how would I fill the entire rectangle with my image so it fits the whole screen as background?

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView, FileChooserIconView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):       
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(source='water.png', pos=(0, 0), size=self.size)        
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]



class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        parent.add_widget(painter)


        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

right now it just displays a small image on the bottom left corner as default. I don't know how to resize or center the image because I don't know what the coordinates for the center are and the image does not resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rectangle is being set to the size of MyPaintWidget, which is being drawn at a default size on the parent widget. If MyPaintWidget were the root widget, then setting self.size would allow it to take up the entire window space. (Note though that the current structure would only resize the canvas on a on_touch_down event. So if you resize the window, you need to click to resize the image.)

```
#Change MyPaintApp to the following...
class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()
```

You could also create a separate widget to hold the background. Below I added a MyBackground widget that is used for the background and is bound to resize when the size of the screen changes. There are several other ways of doing this as well.

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView, FileChooserIconView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MyBackground(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source='water.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.bind(size=self.update_bg)

    def update_bg(self, *args):
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
        self.bg.size = self.size


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = MyBackground()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to write to .kv file.

```
<MyPaintWidget>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'water.png'
```